# Getting live notifications when users register

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm looking to create a notification system for when someone registers to my site. The type of notification system I am wanting is something like stackoverflow has or Facebook. I want a number type notification to appear of how many new registrations I have, but once I click to view the notifications (new registrations) I want the notification alert (like the red square stackoverflow has) to go away.

I am writing this with PHP and have a db table called users that I can pull the users from. I'm just not sure how I can have a notification like this without selecting all of the users to give me a quantity?

So say I have 20 users and 2 new people just registered. I want a notification to display with the number 2. Then when I click on it, for that notification to go away.

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: I have no idea how to go about this. I'm not asking for code, just a way I can go about this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942317/live-notification-jquery This should help.

Answer (score 1):

I am designing systems like this.

The way I do it is to have a structured log of events written by the application into a messaging queue/message broker.

Then I have a message consumer that reads the events and updates any metrics I want out of the system.

In this case, you would need a message consumer that decides on what users should receive what messages (some messages could go to all, some only to specific people).

Each user would have to either poll an API that serves these messages, or have a websocket open to receive the data as a stream (this is faster).

I would place an intermediate storage between the message consumer and the API. I would recommend something light and fast, like Redis, for this.

This is a lot of infrastructure to set up, there are other quick and dirty solutions, but this is quite minimal in my opinion.

Comment: I'm sure this is an awesome answer and I really appreciate your insight. However, this is way too complex for me at this point of time in my coding knowledge. I really just need a way to alert the admin of the site I'm creating that a new user registered so they can go and approve/deny them.

Comment: @Becky How about just sending an email?

Comment: I have an email being sent out already. The notification system would be just an added way to remind the admin when they login to actually approve/deny the new user.

Comment: if it should show **when they log in** it implies that they perform an action, then you should just put a list of unapproved users on the first page they see after login.

Comment: Yes, it should show when they log in, but the way I'm designing my site would conflict like that. Basically when an admin logs in they can see what a standard user sees, but they have an extra nav bar option called admin tools. So I want the notification object to appear on any screen they are on, so if they see an alert they can just click on it and it will take them to a list of unapproved users as you suggested.

Comment: Well, if the information you need is in the database, you just need an HTTP based API that can perform the database query and serve that to an endpoint you can query with Ajax on regular basis (polling) My approach is more for information that is too big to be put into a database.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each users have an unique ID, you can achieve it very simply by yourself adding very few PHP code.

Answer will definitly depend on your own needs and complexity degree you want to achieve, @firelynx answer can be really great if you want to achieve something big and evolvable (you can definitly have some great fun and learn a lot).

However if you only want a very basic implementation I suggest you to create a "notifications" table in your database, you can use (as a minimum) columns [id, user_id, message, new] where new is a tinyInt or any equivalent.

Then add some notifications to the user(s) of your choice, new should be 1 by default. When the user see the notification, just set new to 0 for related notification(s). 
Selecting users that should receive those notifications can then be done depending on user group or some conditions.

If you wanted something simple and not so shinny to begin with, that should do the job well, you can also add a "icon" column to add some fun.

Comment: Thank you. This should be a good start for me. I want only admins of my site to be notified of this and then for every user who registers for that to display as a number with an icon behind it. Then when the icon is clicked on for it to go away.

Comment: Glad it helped, you are probably using a role value in your users table, when someone register, get each users with role = 3 (In this example, 3 would be the admin role -2 can be moderator and 1 user-) and add a notification to each of them. Also, don't forget to save date, you can only display in your "admin navbar" unseen notifications but also maybe between 5 or 10 most recent too. You can do it with only pure PHP, but if you want notifications to appear and be really live when the user just wait on the same web page, add some AJAX like in the question @dipen-shah linked !

Comment: Yes, I have a role system which I call group. I use the hasPermission function. Thanks again.